# Geolocation : Get Formatted Address

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation, google-geocoder, google-geolocation

I've been trying to get formatted address using geolocation for few days now.

I have an on click button that will detect the location based on latitude and longitude. The location will be display on the map with a marker. Also when location is detected the formatted address will be pass to an input field text.

This is the view :

[image: This is the view]

And the code :

```
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" id="address" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA0Sdb3JYcx1VzhCO8iY48ynAHN-a0jQes"></script>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("address").setAttribute('value',address);
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
            } else { 
                alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser');
            }
        }

        function showPosition(geocoder,position,infowindow) {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                  map.setZoom(11);
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map
                });
                  infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                  address.innerHTML=results[0].formatted_address;
              } else {
                  window.alert('No results found');
              }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    }

    function showError(error) {
        switch(error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            alert("User denied the request for Geolocation")
            break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            alert("Location information is unavailable")
            break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
            alert("The request to get user location timed out")
            break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            alert("An unknown error occurred")
            break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I can't seem to get this work. Please help me. Thank you.

Update :

```
document.getElementById("address").setAttribute('value',address);
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
            alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser');
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; 
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            });
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
              address.innerHTML=results[0].formatted_address;
          } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
          }
      } else {
        window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
});
    }

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        alert("User denied the request for Geolocation")
        break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        alert("Location information is unavailable")
        break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
        alert("The request to get user location timed out")
        break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        alert("An unknown error occurred")
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I can't seem to get this work.` what do you observe with this code?

Comment: `function showPosition(geocoder,position,infowindow)` are you **sure** that's the function signature for the callback to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` - *hint, it isn't*, from the documentation, the success callback is described as `A callback function that takes a Position object as its sole input parameter.` - your callback expects **three** arguments

Comment: @Jaromanda X Alright. showPosition should be `function showPosition(position)` and the other argument must be in another function `function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow)` . Is this right?

Comment: don't know really - haven't looked that far into your code - code in the question is *wrong* in the way I mentioned

Comment: @JaromandaX Please see my update, I'm sure I'm still wrong somewhere

Comment: browsers **developer** tools console - check it for errors

Comment: you've got syntax errors, `showError` is not defined, and you still expect 3 arguments in `showPosition` - so, you haven't really changed anything

Comment: Okay I put only the `position` in the `showPosition`. There's no error @JaromandaX

Comment: so, your code produces no error in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: @JaromandaX There's no error but nothing happened

Comment: look at your `showPosition` function ... it does basically nothing

Comment: @JaromandaX Wow I'm really confuse. I put `var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);` inside the `showPosition()` and declare them as `var latlng = latling2;` in `geocodeLatLng()`. Did I succesfully pass the latling to 'geocodeLatLng()' ? And there's no error

Comment: You're still doing nothing with the coordinates

Comment: @JaromandaX What should I do?

Comment: do you see your original `showPosition` ... that - but with the new `showPosition` arguments

Comment: @JaromandaX You mean `var lat = position.coords.latitude; var lng = position.coords.longitude; var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);` ?

Comment: no, I mean the part after that, that actually adds a marker and infoWindow to a map!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169819/discussion-between-iman-yasmin-and-jaromanda-x).